# Word generated XML - Picture 100% width

Tags: ms-word

Currently I'm transforming an XML into another XML with XSLT. I'm using the following to transform the pictures:

```
<w:p wsp:rsidR="005963F5" wsp:rsidRDefault="005963F5" wsp:rsidP="00503709">
  <w:pict>
    <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" >
      <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
      <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
      <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
    </v:shapetype>
    <w:binData w:name="wordml://00000003.png" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="mtext/text()"/></w:binData>
    <v:shape id="Picture1" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:100%; height:auto">
      <v:imagedata src="wordml://00000003.png" o:title="Network"/>
    </v:shape>
  </w:pict>
</w:p>
```

The problem is that the `style="width:100%; height:auto"` doesn't work the way I expect: the pictures are still small like 20x20 in size (or something), but their native size is much larger.

If I use the following, the pictures are as large as their original size, but when opening the XML in Word, the pictures are too large, since they cross the page sheet width boundary:

```
style="width:0px; height:0px"
```

What can I use to make the pictures as large as the width of the Word document. I've also tried this, but only the width is being accounted for, but the height is ignored

```
style="width:600px; height:auto"
```

Any thoughts?